# How to find a list of an object by a nested table?

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate

Such a problem. I have an entity. I need to get a list of objects of this entity by selection, namely by the body_material field. That is, for example, find all BoatCards whose body_material index is 2. I do this in Java using Spring. I have added Dao, Service, Controller and entity's classes

BoatBodyMaterial entity:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "boat_body_material")
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
    public class BoatBodyMaterial {
    
        @Id
        @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
        @Column(name = "matcode")
        private Integer matcode;
    
        @Column(name = "matname")
        private String matname;
    
        @Column(name = "matnote")
        private String matnote;
    
    }
```

BoatCards entity:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "boat_cards")
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@FieldDefaults(level = AccessLevel.PRIVATE)
    public class BoatCards {
    
        @Id
        @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
        @Column(name = "cardid")
        Long cardid;
    
        @Column(name = "reg_num")
        String regNum;
    
        @Column(name = "tiket_num")
        String tiketNum;
    
        @Column(name = "boat_name")
        String boatName;
    
        @ManyToOne
        @JoinColumn(name = "boat_type")
        BoatTypes boatType;
    
        @Column(name = "boat_year")
        String boatYear;
    
        @Column(name = "boat_vin")
        String boatVin;
    
        @Column(name = "parking_place")
        String parkingPlace;
    
        @ManyToOne
        @JoinColumn(name = "sa_category")
        SaCategory saCategory;
    
        @Column(name = "boat_length")
        String boatLength;
    
        @Column(name = "boat_width")
        String boatWidth;
    
        @Column(name = "boat_height")
        String boatHeight;
    
        @ManyToOne
        @JoinColumn(name = "body_material")
        BoatBodyMaterial bodyMaterial;
    
        @Column(name = "boat_payload")
        Long boatPayload;
    
        @Column(name = "passengers_num")
        Long passengersNum;
    
        @Column(name = "service_life")
        String serviceLife;
    
        @Column(name = "engine_num")
        Long engineNum;
    
        @ManyToOne
        @JoinColumn(name = "owner")
        PersonData owner;
    
        @ManyToOne
        @JoinColumn(name = "agent")
        PersonData agent;
    
        @Column(name = "note")
        String note;
    
    }
```

Dao class:

```
public interface BoatCardsDao extends JpaRepository<BoatCards, Integer> {

    @Query(value = "SELECT * from gims.boat_body_material where matcode = 1", nativeQuery = true)
    BoatBodyMaterial findByBodyMaterial ();

    List<BoatCards> findAllByBodyMaterial(BoatBodyMaterial list);
}
```

Service class:

```
public List<BoatCards> getAllByMaterial() {
        BoatBodyMaterial matcodeFromTable = boatCardsDao.findByBodyMaterial();

        List<BoatCards> boatCards = boatCardsDao.findAllByBodyMaterial(matcodeFromTable);
        return boatCards;
    }
```

Controller class:

```
@GetMapping(path="/get")
    public List<BoatCards> get() {

        return boatCardsService.getAllByMaterial();
    }
```

I get ERROR:

```
2023-01-26T10:33:20.193+03:00 ERROR 20852 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed: org.springframework.core.convert.ConversionFailedException: Failed to convert from type [java.lang.Object[]] to type [by.compit.gimsshd.model.BoatBodyMaterial] for value '{1, metal, produce from metal}'] with root cause
```

I resolve this problem! Thank you!

```
public interface BoatCardsDao extends JpaRepository<BoatCards, Integer> {

    List<BoatCards> findAllByBodyMaterialMatcode(Integer bodyMaterial);


}
```

Comment: `select from boat_cards where body_material = 2`

Comment: Shiow me your code

Comment: Where's that "nested table" your title mentions? What you've shown seems to be a simple select with a where condition - and we can't help with the JPA/Hibernate approach since you didn't share any code/mapping to Java entities. So all we can do is suggest a native SQL query like XtremeBaumer already did.

Comment: Please don't be lazy and post your code as text: [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors)

Comment: You might also elaborate on what issue you are facing. Also, since `body_material` is an integer in your table and you're passing a `BoatBodyMaterial` - there might be a mapping issue. You still didn't share the entities themselves. If I'd need to guess I'd assume your `BoatCard` entity just has an `int bodyMaterial` in which case you'd need to map the `BoatBodyMaterial` to an `int` (maybe using `getId()`?) - or yet better: fix your mapping (which we don't know yet).

Comment: @Thomas I added entity and code, thank you!

Comment: @Thomas i added error description

Comment: It's hard to tell what the problem is from that single line of the stack trace you've posted but this seems to be a conversion issue for `BoatBodyMaterial` rather than an issue with the query itself. Again, that single line doesn't help much, e.g. we can't see where exactly the problem arises.

Comment: @Thomas thank you for answer! I resolved this problem. I added description

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
public interface BoatCardsDao extends JpaRepository<BoatCards, Integer> {

    @Query(value = "SELECT card FROM BoatCards card"
            + " JOIN card.bodyMaterial mat"
            + " WHERE mat.matcode = :matcode")
    List<BoatCards> findAllByBodyMaterial(@Param("matcode") int matcode);
}
```

Comment: thank you for answer! I resolved this problem. I added description

Comment: @Yevgeniy yes: it's even simpler